# Xtext autcompletion with qualified names customisation

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, xtext

In the Domainmodel example from the xtext [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#DomainmodelNextSteps) you can reference entities using qualified names. So for example you can write:

```
entity Post extends Org.eclipse.example.MyClass{ 
}
```

Now you cann also use the ctr + space and get the assist: so for the example above would be

```
entity Post extends //use content assist here
{ 
}
```

and you would get a list with Org.eclipse.example.MyClass, and Org.eclipse.example.YourClass *(notice uppercase)*. Assuming there are both defined.

When starting to type the Class name the content assist would just dissapper. In order for it to work properly you would have to type the hole qualified name. Now this is because I am starting the name of my package with upper case what is ussauly not the case in java, but in this DSL the case should not matther.

So do any know how can I customize this behaivior, so the content assit works also with packages starting with upper case?

Update: the problem is the following when starting with upper case the autocompletion will whant to take the hole Qualified name. So in the example when you type a 'O' you get 'Org.eclipse.example.MyClass,Org.eclipse.example.YourClass', but when you type 'M' it goes away. When you change it to lower case (org.eclipse.example.MyClass) then when you type M you get 'MyClass' and when typing 'o' it goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing is negative side effect of an optimization in the proposal provider. Uppercase names are expected to be a part of the simple name (following Java naming conventions). Adapting the content assist prefix matcher is the correct way to adjust for your scenario. For that purpose, you have to bind a custom impl of the `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.PrefixMatcher` or slightly less flexible but easier to implement: the `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.FQNPrefixMatcher.DefaultLastSegmentFinder`.

Comment: Thanks. I used your second suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this article about [case insensitive languages](http://zarnekow.blogspot.fr/2010/06/new-in-xtext-case-insensitive-languages.html).
If you want a case insensitive content assist you only have to modify content assist in mwe2 workflow:

```
fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.ex.ca.ContentAssistParserGeneratorFragment {
    options={
        ignoreCase = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not waht i was looking for. Sorry for not describing the problem taht well. I made an update with a better description

Comment: That option is only necessary if you use case insensitive keywords in your language